# Are any ISEE-3 like returns expected in the foreseeable future?

Tags: probe, flyby, cost, public-involvement

The [crowdsourced effort](http://spacecollege.org/isee3/we-are-now-in-command-of-the-isee-3-spacecraft.html) to re-establish communication with ISEE-3 was a spectacular event enabled, amongst all, by serendipitous trajectory, that brought the probe near Earth after 35 years travel, and still mostly working.

Are trajectories of any other ongoing or finished missions expected to provide similar opportunities in the future?

Comment: Maybe this is a candidate, [Prospero](http://www.universetoday.com/123041/hunting-prospero/#comments)  Launched by the Brittish in 1962. To be visible in December. Such trainspotting in space is way beyond my interest, I just stumbled upon it. David Dickinson seems to be an accomplished amateur astronomer. He enjoys looking at any dot in the sky :-) *Btw, can we invent a smiley which looks through a telescope?*

Comment: www.heavens-above.com is maybe a useful source, as is the community David seems to be starting up. And \.-) is my poor smiley telescope candidate.